# Symfony2: Use different port for Rest API

Tags: api, rest, symfony, https, apache-config

I currently starting a (Symfony2) project where I have to use a different port for HTTP-Communication of the REST-API (JSON/XML) then the normal HTML-Content.

Is this possible? And what is the best practice? Can this be solved by (Symfony-) routing? Goal is to provide the REST-API just for "internal" use (traffic coming from an internal ethernet-connection) and to "block" traffic which comes from a external connection.

**Additional info:**

I add a route /api/user e.g. for the User Rest API and /api/projects for the Project Rest API.

Can I do something like?

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/[Symfony-Folder]/web/api
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if you use bundle like Guzzle, I guess there is option to [set port](https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/guzzle4/http-messages.html#port)

Comment: I think its better if you do it using apache config.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try in your apache config to match your mydomain.tld/api route to a different port.

Also in your config file you can configure défault port like this :

```
# router configuration
router:
    ...
    http_port:            81
```

But I don't know if you can define a port for different routes but maybe you can take a look on the router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this I think :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.tld/api

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

You listen on the port 80 but you redirect the traffic who match the /api path to a different port.